# VBA: Searching an entire collection of classes for a value

Tags: vba, class, collections

I have a collection of simple classes and I would like to search for a specific value in all the classes.

To put it into an example it would look like this:

```
Collection: Employees
Class: Employee 
Employee.Name
Employee.Address
Employee.Salary
```

The data is in a spreadsheet so I'm creating a class for each employee and then store the class into the collection.

So at some point I need to find, lets say, the employee with the highest salary, so I need to search for that value through all the classes.

Can anyone tell how this is done in **VBA**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Collections can be traversed by a `For` statement or a `For Each` statement.

Try (Assuming the Employees collection is 0-based):

```
Dim CtrA as Long, MaxSalary as Currency
MaxSalary = 0
For CtrA = 0 to Employees.Count-1
    If Employees(CtrA).Salary > MaxSalary  Then
        MaxSalary = Employees(CtrA).Salary
    End If
Next
```

Or:

```
Dim Emp as Employee, MaxSalary as Currency
MaxSalary = 0
For Each Emp in Employees
    If Emp.Salary > MaxSalary  Then
        MaxSalary = Emp.Salary
    End If
Next
```

The `For Each` construct may be preferable, since it uses early binding, while the `For` construct may use late binding, meaning that if you get your class members wrong, with early binding you find out on compile, whereas with late binding, you only find out at runtime.

Comment: And is there a way to implement the MaxValue or MinValue methods somehow?

Comment: @user3791958, A VBA `Collection` by itself does not have `MaxValue` or `MinValue` members.  You could make a class that *contains* a `Collection` of whatever type you want, and implement any other members that you need.  However, if you want to know how to do that, that would best be another SO question.